# Getting the console color from a child process

Tags: c, windows, console

I'm trying to write a Windows-equivalent to the [watch command-line tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)) in C.

For spinning up a child process and getting its output, I'm using the approach described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

This works ok for me, but now the output has no colors. For example, a regular `git status` will use green and red to indicate staged and unstaged changes. However, when run as `watch git status` it's all white text.

I'm aware that I can avoid this problem by not redirecting the output. This is not an option however, since I want it to be able to buffer it in my program and potentially manipulate it, before clearing the console and displaying it.

Is it possible to capture the color information from the child process, so I can replicate it in my own output - and if so, how?